# change UNIQUE KEY in customer entity table properties with setup script

Tags: magento-1.9, php, install-script

magento customer_entity table structure is like:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_entity` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id',
  `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set Id',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Id',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Group Id',
  `increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `is_active` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Active',
  `disable_auto_group_change` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Disable automatic group change based on VAT ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID` (`email`,`website_id`),
  ...
```

is it possible to alter the table with install (migration) script to remove UNIQUE KEY property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this to your installer:

```
$connection = $this->getConnection();
$table = $table = $installer->getTable('customer/entity');
$connection->dropIndex($table, 'UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID');
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot, where should i look for such kind of info ? i googled for  '"dropIndex" magento installer' and only sources are showing up, is the only way to know about all the installer methods is looking to the source code? thank you!

Comment: I've searched for `dropIndex` in all the upgrade scripts from magento. I was almost sure there had to be one.